# laravel with mailgun set up

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mailgun

I read everything I can 
and looks like I set it up and fill in everywhere according to the docs (and internet) but still cant receive any emails.

I need to use MailGun API so I can send emails from my localhost as well as from the test and prod + because 25 port usually closed.

I filled in everything I can just in case some miracle happen (was changing between smtp/mailgun in `.env`)

I have tried both my real server settings and when I fail tried without any success sandbox as well.

my mailgun data access (some letters hidden):

1. my mailgun sandbox server
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLxv7.png
2. when i click to it i have an option to choose between API and SMTP
   2.1 in API tab i have API KEY: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaS03.png
   2.2 in SMTP box i have smtp host, port, login, passwd: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMh2T.png
3. my `.env`:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox8ffe89553e224c468f4ad0cf6b4da3c2.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=b3ff30bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx087d-f877bd7a-01ecceaa
```

somewhere in internet found that MAILGUN_DOMAIN & MAILGUN_SECRET
 could be added in `.env` so tried them here as well

4. `config/mail.php`

```
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
```

5. `app/mail/Test.php`

```
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('support@sandbox8ffe89553e224c468f4ad0cf6b4da3c2.mailgun.org')
                    ->subject('HELLO')
                    ->view('test');
    }
```

6. sandbox "to" email verified https://i.stack.imgur.com/raLJQ.png
7. `TestController`

```
use App\Mail\Test;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        echo 'hello';

        try {
            Mail::to('myaddress@gmail.com')->send(new Test());
        } catch  (\Exception $e) {
            dump($e);
        }

        echo 'hello2';

    }
}
```

7. `resources/views/test.blade.php`

```
hello
```

8. was using even so just in case

```
> artisan cache:clear
> artisan config:cache
> artisan cache:clear
```

9

please help, what is missing ? what i did wrong ?

Comment: Check @kopz's answer, that is correct, you need to use .env file constants on mail config file, actually, you will never need to change config/Mail, only need to specify the constants on .env file.

Comment: yes this was the problem partially that i have renamed the keys to values, but i came to it after plays with bells and wistles. The main problem was some why in my config appeared MAIL_FROM_NAME: John Doe with the colon and i didnt receive any kind of errors from laravel or from artisan config:cache. when i saw it, changed colon to = then dropped the cache and artisan said me "hey you cant have white space in config" once whitespace removed everything become working

Comment: good to know, your problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_HOST`, `_PORT`, `_USERNAME`, `_PASSWORD` and `_ENCRYPTION` environment variables apply to **SMTP only.**

For that, your `MAIL_DRIVER` should be set to **SMTP**, with values for the five I just mentioned pointing to your mailgun values.

The `_DOMAIN` and `_SECRET` apply only to when you have set `MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun` (which means the mailgun api), and that means you are **not using SMTP** driver anymore.

Basically you have a choice: pick SMTP and point it to mailgun (set `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`, OR mailgun API (set `MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun`).

I think if you think carefully till you understand the difference between those two, then you should be able to work it out.

Also, on the sandbox domain, you can't send real email unless you add the recipient address as a verified email. You do that on the mailgun dashboard. That might be what is causing the problem here (it is a sandbox after all - it's meant to be safe so you can't accidentally send to live email addresses you haven't specifically opted in with via an email verification by the specific address).

Another tip, go in to tinker and type `config('mail')` and you'll see what is getting picked up by the framework. Then you won't have to adjust the actual config files, if you see the values you want to put there are definitely there.

I also just noticed your config file you listed above is wrong. You have `'driver' => env('mailgun', 'mailgun'),`  That won't work (as you'll see if you do config('mail') in tinker). the env() function takes the name of an environment variable (like MAILGUN_DOMAIN or MAILGUN_SECRET as its first param, the second param is a default value if the shell environment variable of that name doesn't exist).

Comment: i didnt add email to verified - thanks, but main problem was i had in config `MAIL_FROM_NAME: John Doe` and laravel didnt warn me that config is wrong. once i fixed it everything become working :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the name of your ENV setting. In your case you are for example for the username trying to get an env variable named *'postmaster@sandbox8ffexxxxxxxxxxd0cf6b4da3c2.mailgun.org'* that of course does not exist.

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('SUPPORT', 'hello@example.com'), //if SUPPORT env does not exist, default to hello@example.com
    'name' => env('NAME', 'Example'),
],
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('PASSWORD'),
```

when using **env** , first parameter ie. ENV_NAME is the name you have set in your .env file and second (optional) parameter is the value to which it defaults if the first value is not found.

Comment: yes this was the problem partially that i have renamed the keys to values, but i came to it after plays with bells and wistles. The main problem was some why in my config appeared `MAIL_FROM_NAME: John Doe` with the colon and i didnt receive any kind of errors from laravel or from `artisan config:cache`. when i saw it, changed colon to = then dropped the cache and artisan said me "hey you cant have white space in config" once whitespace removed everything become working